# Runinng a ipynb script on many files at once/an entire directory?

Tags: python, pdf, subprocess

I will be the first to tell you that my Python skills are beginner at best, so please forgive my ignorance here.

By way of background, I have created a Python script in Anaconda Jupyter Notebooks that reads a single PDF from a folder, `C:\Users\...\PDFs` , extracts the text of said PDF, and then through some splicing puts the text of interest into a CSV file that it creates.

The problem is that I want to execute this script on *hundreds* of PDFs (the ipynb script itself works just fine when executed on individual PDFs, I just don't want to keep manually changing the file name in the Notebook/Python script). Using pdfreader, my script starts with the following:

```
import pdfreader
from pdfreader import PDFDocument, SimplePDFViewer
fd = open(r'C:Users\...\PDFs\[pdf name].pdf', 'rb')
viewer = SimplePDFViewer(fd) 
doc = PDFDocument(fd)
```

This is where I get stuck - I cannot figure out how to run this on/import all PDFs in the folder. I have seen some people use a variable file name with an asterisk, eg `C:\Users\...\PDFs\*.pdf`, however I can't get that to go. It seems like like it might be possible to save my ipynb as a py file, and then somehow run it in Anaconda Prompt, however I have struggled getting this method to work as well. I am unfamiliar with bat files, but those too seem potentially promising.

Does anyone know of a way to run this script on many PDFs in a single directory at once? I have scrounged around a ton, but for the life of me cannot figure this out. Any help would be greatly appreciated! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `glob` module to gather all of the files names, then loop through them.

```
import pdfreader
from pdfreader import PDFDocument, SimplePDFViewer
from glob import glob

pdf_files = glob(r'C:Users\...\PDFs\*.pdf')

for path in pdf_files:
    fd = open(path, 'rb')
    viewer = SimplePDFViewer(fd) 
    doc = PDFDocument(fd)

    ...
    fd.close()
```

Comment: Brilliant!! Thank you so much James - your solution works beautifully. Cheers